# can't add DataKeyNames into Grid View

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

I'm originally having problems with detecting the status of a checkbox in my grid View.

Apparently one of the solutions to the problem would be adding DataKeyNames value to the Grid View. But if i add DataKey value to my Grid View it's not being populated when I run the code.

Can anybody point me on my mistake?

here is the original head of the grid View which can be populated:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" Width="1500px">
```

Here is the code after i add the DataKeyNames:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    GridLines="None" Width="1500px" DataKeyNames="account_id">
```

And here is the backend code to populate the gridView

```
Dim StrQwery As String = "SELECT account_id, account_name bla bla bla"       
    Dim smd As MySqlCommand
    smd = New MySqlCommand(StrQwery, myconn)
    smd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(smd)
    Dim cb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds)

    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

I can't understand why the values are not filled in Grid View after I add DatakeyNames

the entire code of Grid View

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" Width="1500px"  >
        <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateField >
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" textAlign="right" 
                             /> 
                        </ItemTemplate>

                    </asp:TemplateField>



          </Columns>
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you post the ASPX code where you define your GridView columns?  Just so I'm clear, you're not able to see if a checkbox is checked ... or it's not filling in the checkbox checked value based on the value in your DB table?

Comment: Hi Adam. I don't define colums in aspx. because if I do. it becomes duplicated. I just populate Grid View from VB

Comment: But I will post the entire code of grid View wait